# No pre-launch report available, Google Play App Rejected due to Designed for Families Stability Issue

Tags: android, google-play, stability

I just got a message from Google Play saying that my latest APK (Build 12) fails their Designed for Families stability test. But they don't give me any details on what actually happened, so I'm at a loss for what to change.

I tried looking for the pre-launch report, but the last pre-launch report was for APK 9 and there is nothing after that. So how the heck am I supposed to know what problem they encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [Android Developer Blog Post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/building-safer-google-play-for-kids.html).

From what I gather, you are supposed to consider if children are a part of your target audience. If children are a part of your target audience then adjust your app content and if it doesn't change the age group and make sure it doesn't appeal to children.